# Does this function return the same pointer as its argument?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have written this function in C:

```
void *PWNRetain(void *object) {
  PWNObject *obj = (PWNObject *)object; // <-- looks stupid, I know :)
  obj->retainCount++;
  return obj;
}
```

It's important that this will return the same pointer as it's argument. Is `obj` equal to `object`, or did I make another pointer mistake? Thanks. :)

Comment: You don't need to return that pointer, just make it `void PWNRetain(void* object)`.

Comment: I **do** need to return that pointer. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: I just gotta wonder, why not do `return object;` at the end?

Comment: @Dan, because it doesn't matter in any single way. `return obj;` gives smaller code thus faster compilation.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well, in that case you could just rename `object` to `o` and do `return o;`. Even smaller code and even faster compilation. :p

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this will return the same pointer in C.  In fact, you don't need the explicit cast on the second line, as C allows implicit conversions from `void *` to other pointer types.

Comment: If his answer answered the question, you should mark it as accepted (big tick underneath the number on the left).

Answer (score 0):

Typically, people will use a forward declaration of their struct to enable type-safety, but your code will function as expected and does indeed return the same pointer.